# Constraints on Generics with VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

I have the a function that is declared like so:

```
Public Sub Modify(Of SIMType As {New, DAOBase})(ByVal obj As SIMType)
```

I also have a class called `Products` which is declared like so:

```
Public Class Products
Inherits DAOBase
```

So as you can see, if I were to call this function like so:

```
Modify(Of Products)(new Products())
```

This would not be an issue. The issue actually arises when I try to cast the object being past in to its real type. For example:

```
CType(obj, Products)
```

or

```
CType(obj, SIMType)
```

Both do not work. I get this error:

> Value of type SIMTYPE cannot be converted to IMS.Products.

I'm assuming this is because I am using generics. Is there a way to adjust my function to allow for a casting operation like I am trying to do? In the end, what I need is a reference of the actual type (Products in this case) to the object.

Comment: Currently this comes up quite high when google "vb net generic constraints", so I'd like to clarify what is going on. First, Olivier's answer shows that in this specific case, a generic constraint is not the best approach -- you don't need generic at all, you just need to use standard Object-Oriented programming, with a method in the base class that is overridden in subclasses. Second, if you really do want (code smell) code to work with a given type, do this:  `If TypeOf obj Is Products Then`, `Dim p As Products = DirectCast(obj, Products)`. Now you can work with `p`. But try to avoid this.

Comment: BTW, the problem isn't "because you are using generics", rather it is because your parameter type isn't specific enough for the conversion to be valid. You would get a similar error with an ordinary (not generic) function having parameter of type `DAOBase`. In both cases, the solution involves use of `DirectCast` or `TryCast`.

Answer (score 2):

You can move your modify method to DAOBase and make it overridable:

```
Public Class DAOBase
    Public Overridable Sub Modify()
        ' Work on DAOBase here
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Products
    Inherits DAOBase

    Public Overrides Sub Modify()
        ' Work on Products here, without having to cast.
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can then call Modify on all types which derive from DAOBase:

```
Dim obj As DAOBase = New Products()
obj.Modify()  ' Calls Products.Modify, even if obj is declared as DAOBase.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast `obj` to `Products`, because there is no constraint that ensures that this conversion is valid, so the compiler assumes it's not valid. Anyway, if your method is generic, it's not supposed to have specific code for specific type parameters. If you need to do something specific when `SIMType` is `Products`, create a new overload of the `Modify` method.

Comment: There are many situations where it can be helpful for generic types to have special-case handling of some particular types.  Among other things, one may have a generic type `Woozle(of T)` which calls `Modify` on a parameter of its type `T` that may or may a type for which special handling exists.  If a type would only work with some particular selected types, it should probably be an interface rather than a class, but there's nothing wrong with a generic class that works with all types but works especially well with some special ones.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Olivier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8512835/199364) - this is traditional Object-Oriented programming, where the method in each class knows what to do, based on the class it is in. No casts required; an appropriate `Modify` is called in all cases.

However, it is useful to know alternatives, so here is a way to accomplish the casting that is asked about in the question:

```
Public Sub Modify(Of SIMType As {New, DAOBase})(ByVal obj As SIMType)
    Dim products1 As Products = TryCast(obj, Products)
    If products1 IsNot Nothing Then
        ... ' here you can use products1
    End If
End Sub
```

CAVEAT: Any time you find yourself using `TryCast` or `DirectCast`, ask yourself if there isn't some alternative solution that does not require casting. Yes, that alternative likely requires some "refactoring" of your existing code, but in the long run, that refactoring is probably worth it.